# clear and test bit in single statement in C

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I would like to clear, and test a particular bit in single statement, for instance to clear bit 27 and test the same bit, and wanted to return the status for same:

```
{
    status = number & BIT(27);

    if (status)
        number & ~BIT(27);

    return number & BIT(27);
}
```

Is there way to do it using Ternary operator ?

Comment: I don't understand the point of this code: it will *always* return 0. Did you maybe intend to `return status;'` at the end? Also, the `if (status)` check is unnecessary.

Comment: The body of the `if()` does not assign the result of the operation. Either that is a bug, or you could get rid of that pointless line, too...

Comment: Why "... in a single statement" ?

Comment: It there any particular reason why you can't just clear the bit no matter what value it holds? Since your pseudo code here doesn't preserve `status` anyway. Similarly, what is the reason why you do `return number & BIT(27);` and not `return 0`? Which of these variables are volatile and what's their special meaning?

Comment: Since you tagged [tag:linux-kernel], if this is required in Linux kernel code, you could use its [`test_and_clear_bit`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-test-and-clear-bit.html) function.

Comment: Milan, the unanswered [Why "... in a single statement" ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75359371/clear-and-test-bit-in-single-statement-in-c?noredirect=1#comment132973054_75359371) is important.

Comment: @IanAbbott the issue one may not easily find or debug is that the mentioned function **does require** `unsigned long` (casting is a very bad idea, if somebody thinks of) and it's a crucial detail.

Comment: @0andriy That's true and also the bit number is not restricted to values below `BITS_PER_LONG` so it can work on an array of `unsigned long` with  `BITS_PER_LONG` bits per element. There are also GCC built-in intrinsic functions for atomic bit manipulation that can work on any unsigned integer type, but I can't think of any Linux kernel code that uses them.

Answer (score 3):

The code fragment does not modify `number` so it will return the bit value but not clear it.  You probably meant this instead:

```
#define BIT(n)  (1U << (n))  // assuming this definition for BIT or similar

{
    status = number & BIT(27);

    if (status)
        number &= ~BIT(27);

    return status;
}
```

You can indeed achieve this in a single expression using the ternary operator and a comma expression:

```
    return (number & BIT(27)) ? (number &= ~BIT(27), BIT(27)) : 0;
```

or this alternative:

```
    return (number & BIT(27)) ? (number ^= BIT(27), BIT(27)) : 0;
```

There is a sequence point between the evaluation of the test expression and the evaluation of the second or third expression, so it is OK to modify `number` this way as a side effect.

This approach may allow you to encapsulate the test and clear trick inside an expression macro, but be aware that this macro would evaluate `number` twice. You might consider an inline function taking the address of `number`:

```
static inline int test_and_clear27(int *number) {
    if (*number & BIT(27)) {
        *number &= ~BIT(27);
        return BIT(27);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Or without branches:

```
static inline int test_and_clear27(int *number) {
    int status = *number & BIT(27);
    *number &= ~BIT(27);
    return status;
}
```

These methods are not thread safe: it cannot be used to implement semaphores as the test and clear operations are separate and do not happen atomically.

Comment: Ok my bad, I see what you are doing now. Still this is needlessly obscure, `if-else` would have been more readable.

Comment: Accessing number by address twice is not good idea. Might have a side effect to make debugging harder.

Comment: @0andriy: as I mentioned in the last paragraph, this method is not atomic.  I am not sure what side effect could make debugging harder.

Comment: Besides atomicity you have _data integrity_. And the last one is the issue with your excerpt.

Comment: @0andriy: I don't understand your point: the pointer is a function argument, how could accessing the number twice via this pointer cause side effects different from the intended effect of clearing the bit ? (assuming single threaded execution and non-`volatile` data for `number`.

Comment: You are accessing `number` twice. In between it can be changed (due to data integrity is not provided).

Comment: @0andriy: the compiler may actually assume that it does not change since `number` is not `volatile` qualified` and no other `int` is modified either explicitly or via a pointer (the local variable `status` cannot be pointed to by `number`) .  And as I have mentioned, if the data can be changed asynchronously by another thread, the approach is doomed.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code does not do what your description claims. Instead, it is equivalent to

```c
return number & BIT(27);
```

— A nice, concise, single statement.

However, assuming that you actually *do* wanted to clear bit 27, the following code does that (the `if` in your code is unnecessary):

```c
status = number & BIT(27);
number &= ~ BIT(27);
return status;
```

There’s really no good reason to rewrite this as a single statement (except by encapsulating it inside a function<sup>1</sup>). But, just for argument’s sake, it is possible. [chqrlie has already posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75359707/1968), but if you only use `status` as a boolean flag you can shorten the code and remove the conditional operator:

```c
return (number & BIT(27)) && (number &= ~ BIT(27), 1);
```

Is this better than the three-statement solution? [*Absolutely not!*](https://godbolt.org/z/EnxhsTs1T) On the contrary: it introduces a branch into the logic which, if anything, makes this code slower.

---

<sup>1</sup> And as per [Ian Abbott’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75359371/clear-and-test-bit-in-single-statement-in-c/75359707#comment132974524_75359371) the Linux kernel provides just such a function: [`test_and_clear_bit()`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-test-and-clear-bit.html), but be careful since it requires to have a variable of `unsigned long` type and any casting to it is a very bad idea.

Comment: @0andriy Please don't perform gratuitous edits that clearly conflict with the author intent. Could you please explain (1) why you add the completely unnecessary Markdown language tags and (2) to what extent my shortened mention of `unsigned long` is insufficient compared to your phrasing, which (IMHO) is less understandable since it obscures the relevant fact (argument data type) behind unimportant/implied details which decrease the signal-to-noise ratio?

Comment: 1. The `\`\`\`` notation without specific `lang` options does **not** always work. If somebody looks at your answer source they won't find the proper example of how to use the `lang` directive.

Comment: 2. Casting to `unsigned long` on 64-bit architectures may lead to a serious issues, all the same for the 32-bit architectures in case the accessed type is smaller than 32-bit. Altogether there are three issues with that. That's why it's very important note.